# Sort new array?

Tags: arrays, filtering, array-filter

I got this array

```
$arr =('1-1.jpg','1-2.jpg','11-3.jpg', '1-4.jpg', '3-5.jpg', '41-5.jpg','1-3.jpg','4-5.jpg','14-5.jpg','54-5.jpg','64-5.jpg','14-5.jpg', '1-5.jpg');
```

I need this array

```
$newarray=('1-1.jpg','1-2.jpg','1-3.jpg', '1-4.jpg', '1-5.jpg');
```

I got this function

```
$new =array_filter( $arr, function( $el) { 
return substr( $el, 0, 2) == '1-';; 
});
```

But always i got this error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION**

Comment: It looks like you are just filtering, but your title and tags refer to sorting. How is this related to sorting?

Comment: I'd say, upgrade your php version to something > v5.3

Comment: Yes, if i comment function, all working nice, but always problem with that?

Comment: Nice mate, but problem is that on server i got older version, can someone help me to modify function?

Comment: ref: [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Actually this is just a matter of syntax (regarding your old php version). Have a look at the examples in the manual for [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) or on [callables](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.callable.php) in general and you're set.

Comment: I am trying a entire day:( No luck always syntax error, can you write it, thanks a lot mate ?

Comment: I tried this    function($arr) { 
     $provera= substr($arr, 0, 2) == '1-'; 
     };
     $new =array_filter($slike, $provera);